# Create a custom ZODB in Plone?

Tags: plone, zodb

I need to store some information and be able to read and write this information. Can I create a custom small ZODB (http://www.zodb.org/en/latest/articles/ZODB1.html) and have Plone read/write to this? Would placing it in /var/filestorage/myzodb.fs cause any issues with the existing Plone and the database it uses?

Comment: What is the Use-Case? Does another service access the DB directly?

Comment: Plone won't care about unknown fs files in the firestorage directory, but I agree with Mathias, using another zodb seems… quaint without knowing exactly what your situation is.

Comment: You can always use annotations to store non-schema related information on objects ;) https://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/misc/annotations.html#content-annotations

Comment: I posted a link to your question on our forum at https://community.plone.org/t/stack-overflow-create-a-custom-zodb-in-plone/4392

Comment: The use case is I make a call to get some values and I need to save them so next time I don't need to make the same call. Occasionally, I'll need to repeat this call to get new values but for the most part, it's stays the same and Plone just needs to read them. I need these values to persist even through Plone restarts. No other service uses needs to read these values.

Comment: You can mount a seperate ZODB inside a plone site. However its not recommended except in special circumstances. The reason is, that you need to ensure there are no references that cross between databases. 

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/plone-users/JiBaqAk0RwA

Answer (score 4):

As I said before, you can always use **annotations** to store non-schema related information on objects:

```
>>> from persistent.list import PersistentList
>>> from persistent.dict import PersistentDict
>>> from zope.annotation.interfaces import IAnnotations

>>> anno = IAnnotations(self.context)

>>> anno['employees'] = PersistentList(['Mary', 'Jo', 'Bob'])
>>> anno['codes'] = PersistentDict({'a': 1, 'b': 2})
```

See [docs](https://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/misc/annotations.html#content-annotations) for more details

If you still want to store data to different **ZODB** file, you should take care of 3 major issues:

- **Scaling**
- **DB connections**
- **DB read/write conflict errors**

To scale it up, you should use [ZEO](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.recipe.zeoserver) (or [RelStorage](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/RelStorage/1.6.3)). I will suppose you're using [zc.buildout](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zc.buildout) to deploy your Plone stack. Thus, within **buildout.cfg**:

```
[zeoserver]
recipe = plone.recipe.zeoserver
zeo-address = 127.0.0.1:8100
...
zeo-conf-additional =
    <filestorage 2>
      path ${buildout:directory}/var/myzodb.fs
    </filestorage>

[instance]
recipe = plone.recipe.zope2instance
...
zeo-client = True
zeo-address = 127.0.0.1:8100
zope-conf-additional =
  <zodb_db myzodb>
      <zeoclient>
          server 127.0.0.1:8100
          storage 2
          name myzodbstorage
      </zeoclient>
      mount-point /myzodb
  </zodb_db>
```

Now, to connect and store data to this new DB:

```
>>> from App.config import getConfiguration
>>> from zope.component.hooks import getSite

>>> db = getConfiguration().dbtab.getDatabase(name='myzodb')    
>>> conn = getSite()._p_jar.get_connection('myzodb')
>>> myzodb = conn.root()
>>> myzodb
{}

>>> myzodb['employees'] = ['Mary', 'Jo', 'Bob']
>>> myzodb['codes'] = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}

>>> import transaction
>>> transaction.commit()
```

Comment: If the amount of data is larger, you might want to use OOBtree instead of PersistentDict. See https://www.slideshare.net/carlos.delaguardia/zodb-tips-and-tricks

Answer (score 0):

You can also use souper for light weight data:

```
>>> from souper.soup import get_soup
>>> soup = get_soup('my_soup_id', context)
>>> soup
<souper.soup.Soup at 0x...>
```

It also supports indexing.